# Show loading gif when DataTable has been cleared

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, datatable

I have several options for my JQuery datatable which will clear the DataTable and load new data via WebSockets. Therefore I clear the Table contents with `fnClearTable()`and a few moments later I get the new data via my WebSocket.

**This can last up to a few seconds and in the meantime I would like to display a loading image in my DataTable. How can I achieve this?**

**My event handler which clears the DataTable**:

```
/* On Daterange change (e.g. Last 3 Days instead of Last 24h) */

    $('#profitList_dateRange').change(function() {
        var dateRangeHours = $("#profitList_dateRange").val();
        var jsonParamObject = JSON.parse(dateRangeHours);

        // Clear table
        var profitList = $('#profitList').dataTable();
        profitList.fnClearTable(); // Now I want to show the loading image!
        socket.emit('load-statistics', (jsonParamObject));
    });
```

Comment: What if you had the gif on the page hidden. Then once the change function is fired, show it, and once the clear function is complete hide the gif again with a callback.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve it is if you have 2 divs (I assume that your divs are properly styled to the content inside of them):

```
<div id="profitList"> your table content </div>
<div id="profitListLoading"> show loading here </div>
```

Then in your handler:

```
$('#profitList_dateRange').change(function() {
        var dateRangeHours = $("#profitList_dateRange").val();
        var jsonParamObject = JSON.parse(dateRangeHours);

        // Clear table
        var profitList = $('#profitList').dataTable();
        profitList.fnClearTable(); // Now I want to show the loading image!
        $('#profitList').hide();
        $('#profitListLoading').show();
        socket.emit('load-statistics', (jsonParamObject));
    });
```

In your handling of loaded data you should ofc. revert the change

```
        $('#profitList').show();
        $('#profitListLoading').hide();
```

Comment: I don't think this a good way to do it as this is not taking advantage of the DT feature of "processing" div, this means you would have to worry about styling the div, positioning it in the right place and make sure it is responsive (if you care about that) Using `processing` option would be better IMO

Comment: I agree. I as not aware of this feature, and offered a generic solution.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `processing: true`

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    processing: true
});
```

Then add:

```
$('.dataTables_processing', $('#example').closest('.dataTables_wrapper')).show();
```

If you want to add a GIF image you can change the markup as follows:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
  oLanguage: {
    sProcessing: "<img src='https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/12755/screenshots/1037374/hex-loader2.gif'>"
  },
  processing: true
});
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/0m6uo54t/2

processing:

> Enable or disable the display of a 'processing' indicator when the
>   table is being processed (e.g. a sort). This is particularly useful
>   for tables with large amounts of data where it can take a noticeable
>   amount of time to sort the entries.

https://datatables.net/reference/option/processing

[UPDATE] `bProcessing` is the legacy option, the new DT code uses `processing`

Comment: what means the bProcessing flag?

Comment: See my update, it basically enables showing an hiding the processing div

Comment: I have tried this approach by adding this line `$('.dataTables_processing', $('#profitList').closest('.dataTables_wrapper')).show();`into my change event handler after fnClearTable but it seems like it's not working. I have set processing to true when creating the datatable. Behaviour hasn't change (it says No data available) after clearing the table instead of showing a loading animation.